# Mac library for properties of an app

Tags: java, directory

I know that I can use System.getProperty("user.home") gets the default home for files and is usually where I put my property files for my applications. But I want a more "discrete" location for my files so that library won't get cluttered (since that library is usually seen by the user). Does anybody know how I can get a directory like that?

Comment: Library can be seen by the user, but most never bother to look. And it's the correct place for settings. Why don't you think it's appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a folder where the name starts with '.' so that it won't be shown in the Finder by default. For example `System.getProperty("user.home")+"/.mydocs";`

On Unix systems, by default, folders with a name starting with a '.' are hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Look over [java.util.prefs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/prefs/package-summary.html). This API is designed to give you access to user prefs in a system-independent way.

In OS X this is backed by access to ~/Library/Preferences, see [this documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1170/_index.html) for details.

If the user-specific data that you're trying to store isn't strictly *preferences*, the same document recommends:

```
System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Library/" + "Your App Name"
```